# gremlin shortestPath() with(ShortestPath.edges, Direction.OUT)

Tags: gremlin, shortest-path

with(ShortestPath.edges, Direction.OUT)
what is this option?
how is work?
what is the difference ?
I cannot understand the explain.
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#shortestpath-step

I want to know more concretely.
I try this.
It faster than default Direction.BOTH.

these two option make result difference? and when?

Comment: I may be understanding this logic.
Direction.OUT option makes me walk ahead to the target.
On the contrary, Direction.IN option makes me Walk backwards to the target.
is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will make it easier for you : (Direction.Both its same as Direction.IN + Direction.OUT)

based on this graph : https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-computing

```
g.V('4').shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges,Direction.OUT).with(ShortestPath.maxDistance,1).with(ShortestPath.includeEdges,true)
```

==>[v[4]]

==>[v[4],e[11][4-created->3],v[3]]

==>[v[4],e[10][4-created->5],v[5]]

```
g.V('4').shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges,Direction.IN).with(ShortestPath.maxDistance,1).with(ShortestPath.includeEdges,true)
```

==>[v[4],e[8][1-knows->4],v[1]]

==>[v[4]]

and DIRECTION.BOTH will be the In and Out Edges

```
g.V('4').shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.edges,Direction.BOTH).with(ShortestPath.maxDistance,1).with(ShortestPath.includeEdges,true)
```

==>[v[4],e[8][1-knows->4],v[1]]

==>[v[4],e[10][4-created->5],v[5]]

==>[v[4]]

==>[v[4],e[11][4-created->3],v[3]]

also you should see the default value , i made maxdistance 1 to make it easier